# how chrome.runtime.onUpdateAvailable.addListener will work for extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am creating an extension and I want to autoupdate my .crx file if any update is available, so can anyone tell me how this listener works with the extension and when it will be fired.

```
chrome.runtime.onUpdateAvailable.addListener(function (details) {    
  console.log("updating to version " + details.version);
  chrome.runtime.reload();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`chrome.runtime.onUpdateAvailable`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#event-onUpdateAvailable) event is fired

> when an update is available, but isn't installed immediately because the app is currently running.

Meaning it has no part in actually getting the update. To handle updating your app, you can either publish it through the Crhome App store or use the [`update_url`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/autoupdate.html) field in the manifest to let it know when there is an update.

Comment: Can you give more details and some more links for this?

Comment: @AnkitPanwar I don't understand, there is no need for more info or links. If you publish your extension in the app store then it will update when you update the version in the store. If you choose to host it yourself then just follow the instructions in the link.

Comment: Actually BeardFist i have hosted my extension on my localhost then i am bit confused how it will work?

Comment: @AnkitPanwar If you are hosting it on localhost as you said, then there is no reason to even try making it auto update. The non CWS requires the update manifest to be updated when there is a change, and while you could automate that as well it would be far easier to just reload it manually. Especially since you don't need to pack it to begin with if you are only using it locally.

Comment: No BeardFist I don't to reload my extension.Actually i have packed my extension then i have hosted my .crx file on my localhost and then i want to check any update on server on click on button.if yes then update my .crx file from the server.

Comment: It seems to be a lot of unnecessary work if you are only using it locally. As for checking if there is an update, you can't do that programmatically. That is something performed by chrome every so often, or if you press the `update extensions now` button.

Comment: can you give your email id? for discussion.

Comment: Thanks for your comments Mr.BeardFist. Actually I have hosted my extension on port 87 at localhost. But Chrome doesn't like to update from non-80 ports.when i change port 87 to 80 my code work perfectly.One more thing all the rest of things chrome take-care itself that time you are also absolutely right Mr.BeardFist for this.
So many thanks Mr.BeardFist.